# get a word after specific word/character from .txt file

Tags: c#

to the point, i've problem with getting word/string after specific word or character from .txt file, this is the txt file

> andrea = bad
>   john = good
>   rob = evil

so when input is **andrea** the output is **bad**, when input **john** the output is **good**, and when input is **rob** the output is **evil**

i just want the word after "=" are showed up when first word is inputted, all lines in the file structured like that.

sorry for my poor english, i hope you understand what i asked

Comment: Please add some more information to your question: is "X = Y" on its line, or is that embedded among other text? Are all lines in the file structured like that? Do you intend to search something in the text file, or do you want to read the text file once and then store the data in memory? Does every name on the left-hand side appear only once, or can one person have several attributes?

Comment: edited just now, i hope u understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dict = File.ReadLines(filename)
                    .Select(line => line.Split('='))
                    .Where(parts => parts.Length>1)
                    .ToDictionary(x=>x[0].Trim(), x=>x[1].Trim());

Console.WriteLine(dict["andrea"]);
```

Comment: A code fragment for mindless copy-and-pasting without any explanation on how and why it works and what principles and ideas were used is not useful at all to future visitors with similar problems. Arguably, it does not really "help" the OP in a long-term perspective, either.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This all I can do, post your own answer then.

Comment: +1 I would be inclined to use regular expressions, but I like this answer. It shows I could (should?) use Linq a lot more.

Comment: is it possible getting the text with StreamReader ?

Comment: @user2398681 of course, Read line by line, split every line by `=` and put parts to a dictionary. But I gave above answer intentionally. If you need it for learning it can be a good start but if you want a code to copy/paste for your homework, your professor will probably not accept it :)

Comment: actually i'm not an IT student, and i've interest in programming, i've  learned VB before, and it seems easier than C#, anyway , would you mind to share it?